# How to construct a grammar that generates language L?

Tags: grammar, automata-theory

I'm in a Formal languages class and have a grammar quiz coming up. I'm assuming something like this will appear.

Consider the alphabet ∑ = {a, b, c}.  Construct a grammar that generates the language L = {bab^nabc^na^p : n ≥ 0, p ≥ 1}. Assume that the start variable is S.

Comment: I believe this would be more appropriate in http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i think you're right. Do I have to delete the question?

Comment: Blind leading the blind here. I would assume its correct to do so.

Comment: I can't find the delete but I think leaving the question here would still be helpful because cs.stackexachange.com is in beta, so not as many people could be on.

Comment: @TerryLight, please, don't delete the question.

Comment: @TerryLight, please, do not take my answer as a surely correct one, since I have not worked with formal languages for a really long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a very long time since I worked with formal languages for the last time, so, please, forgive my rustyness, but this would be the language: We divide `S` to a prefix variable (`A`) and a suffix variable (`B`). Then, we handle the prefix and the suffix separately, both of them have a possible rule of further recursion, and an end sign of empty, where no occurrence is required and the constant where at least an occurrence is required.

```
{bab^nabc^na^p : n ≥ 0, p ≥ 1}

S -> ASB
A -> babAabc
A -> {empty}
B -> Ba
B -> a
```